# Get last edited table if 2 table have the same columns parameters - mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following database :

| Filename | Edited | PARAMETER1 | PARAMETER2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1.csv | 2022-06-08 17:23:16 | RED | BLUE |
| file2.csv | 2022-06-09 15:54:45 | GREEN | YELLOW |
| file3.csv | 2022-06-15 14:52:40 | RED | BLUE |

As file1.csv and file3.csv have the same value in PARAMETER1 & PARAMETER2 i want only the last edited between file1.csv and file3.csv

| Filename | Edited | PARAMETER1 | PARAMETER2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file2.csv | 2022-06-09 15:54:45 | GREEN | YELLOW |
| file3.csv | 2022-06-15 14:52:40 | RED | BLUE |

Tried groupby but can't then get time column.

Edit: @Guido Faecke solution worked for me.
But i ended up going for :

```
SELECT u1.* 
FROM DATABASE u1 
WHERE 
 u1.Edited = (SELECT 
MAX(u2.Edited) 
   FROM DATABASE u2 
   WHERE u2.PARAMETER1= u1.PARAMETER1 AND u2.PARAMETER2 = u2.PARAMETER2);
```

Comment: Can you show some SQL you have written so far?

Comment: @GuidoFaecke Hi, yes of course, so i'm pretty new to mySQL. As far as i've got is : SELECT Filename FROM table
GROUP BY PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2 But i have a count and not just the files with these two parameters

Comment: But i group first by parameter1 then parameter2, so not the solution at all. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT 
  filename, 
  edited, 
  parameter1, 
  parameter2 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    filename, 
    edited, 
    parameter1, 
    parameter2, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY parameter1, parameter2 ORDER BY edited DESC) file_rank
  FROM 
    my_table as t2
) as t1 where file_rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I ended up using this : SELECT 
    u1.*
FROM
    DATABASE u1
WHERE
    u1.Edited= (SELECT 
            MAX(u2.Edited)
        FROM
            DATABASE u2
        WHERE
            u2.PARAMETER1= u1.PARAMETER1 AND u2.PARAMETER2 = u2.PARAMETER2);